# Is there any way of having customised button for different users based on the information in the firebase

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement a request button that if click on it should turn into a request send the way Facebook works

I tried to implement this But I am having issues

Below is the approach I used

```
class _TherapistRequestState extends State<TherapistRequest> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> therapists = FirebaseFirestore
      .instance.collection('users')
      .where('role', isEqualTo: 'Therapist')
      .snapshots();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String ? therapist;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              'MAISHA BORA',
              style: GoogleFonts.aclonica(
                textStyle:const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor.withOpacity(0.9),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Available Therapist',
                style: GoogleFonts.aclonica(
                    color: kPrimaryColor,
                    fontSize: 25,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const Divider(
            color: kPrimaryColor,
            height: 20,
          ),
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: therapists,
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
                if(snapshot.hasData){
                  final data = snapshot.requireData;
                  return ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(
                        height: size.height * 0.7,
                        width: size.width
                      ),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: data.size,
                        itemBuilder: (context, i){
                          therapist = data.docs[i]['uid'];
                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              Card(
                                shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                                elevation: 10.0,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            'Dr ${data.docs[i]['username']}',
                                            style: GoogleFonts.acme(
                                              textStyle:const TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                fontSize: 20,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            'Patients ${data.docs[i]['patients']}/4',
                                            style: GoogleFonts.aladin(
                                              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.grey,
                                                fontSize: 20,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                        children: [
                                          buildButton(context),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        }
                    ),
                  );
                }
                else{
                  return Container();
                }
              },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget buildButton(context){
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(therapist).collection('request').doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
          if(snapshot.data.exists){
            return SquareButton(
                label: 'Request Sent',
                color: Colors.grey,
                onPressed: (){
                  null;
                }
            );
          }
          return SquareButton(
            label: 'Request',
            color: Colors.green,
            onPressed: () async{
              FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
                  .doc(therapist)
                  .collection('request')
                  .doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid)
                  .set({
                'userId' : _auth.currentUser!.uid,
              }).then((value) {
                showToast(
                  message: 'Request sent successfully',
                  color: Colors.green,
                );
              });
            },
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

But when I use this, if I go to the page I get this error

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder flutter

which I suppose is when I try to check the state of the button

How can tackle this using a different method.

Please do assist me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that instead of using a stream, you can fetch the data from firebase once. To do that, you can define a future on top of your state and assign it a value in your `initState`
In your build method you can use a FutureBuilder around the button you want to customize

**EDIT**
You can do something like this:

```
class _TherapistRequestState extends State<TherapistRequest> {
    Future required_document;
    initHelper()async{     //using this function because we need to use async await    
        required_document = await FirebaseCollection.......doc();
    }
    initState(){
        initHelper();
    }
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
            return Container(); 
        // enclose your button that needs to be customized in a FutureBuilder like so:
            // FutureBuilder(
            // future: required_document,
            // builder:(a,b){return ElevatedButton()} 
            //)
            
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I tackle this 
Can you illustrate using an example

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please check it out and let me know if you need any help

Comment: And if I want to get a specific doc based on the value in the ListView builder?

Comment: yes you can do that. But can you tell me how the indexes from listview builder are related to your actual docs in the firestore?

Comment: The index are data from one collection but I have a sub collection that saves the request and it is the one I want to use to know if a request has already been send or not so that I can update the request button

Comment: Assuming your index value is `idx` from Listview builder, you can do this
`QuerySnapshot collectionSnap = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('desired_collection').get();
List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = collectionSnap.docs()
`
and you can then reference each doc with `docs[idx]`